# Terminal settings reset

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I add scrip to run on terminal start.

I forgot unchecked "Exit after script run" or so.

Now my terminal keeps closing and i can't run it!

How do i reset that option ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `dconf-editor` and navigate to org > gnome > terminal > legacy > profiles. Here choose your profile by its internal ID (if you have multiple then just go though them to find the right one) and fix `custom-command` to be the empty string, or `exit-action` to be `hold` or `restart`.

*Update:* Another solution that just occurred to me is to execute `gnome-terminal -e bash` and then simply fix it the Preferences dialog.

Comment: Got it... Working now ;)